# Find all indexes of row and cols in dataframe by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have a dataframe with numeric values.

how can i find all indexes ("row"+"col"+"Value") of cells above\under certain threshold?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and my threshold is 2
i would like to get:

```
[[0,c,3],[1,a,4][1,b,5],[1,c,6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, create columns by `MultiIndex`, filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and last convert to `nested list`s:

```
c = df.stack().reset_index(name='val').query('val > 2').values.tolist()
print (c)
[[0, 'c', 3], [1, 'a', 4], [1, 'b', 5], [1, 'c', 6]]
```

Another numpy solution for better performance:

```
#create numpy array
arr = df.values
#create boolean mask
m =  arr > 2
#get positions ot True values
a = np.where(m)
#filter values to 1d array by mask
b = arr.ravel()[m.ravel()]

#final list by indexinf columns and index values, map for convert nested tuples
c = list(map(list, zip(df.index[a[0]], df.columns[a[1]], b)))
print (c)
[[0, 'c', 3], [1, 'a', 4], [1, 'b', 5], [1, 'c', 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[df.gt(2)].stack().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'c', 3.0], [1, 'a', 4.0], [1, 'b', 5.0], [1, 'c', 6.0]]
```